# Can "whose names I've called" be used before any names were called?

Tags: tense, grammaticality

During a school event the teacher said

> The students whose **names I've called** will come up onstage

But till that time she hadn't called anyone

So shouldn't it be "the students whose **names I call** will come up onstage"?

Answer (score 1):

She could say either. *I've called* is looking back from the time when the people will come up to the stage. *I call* is looking forward from now.

Both are equally good.

Answer (score 0):

We could use - going to call.

> The students whose names I am going to call will come up onstage

**Going to** is used when a plan has already been made. Here in the sentence above your teacher has already made a plan to call the names of students. And then those students will have to go on stage, which is an action in the future, so "will" is used there.

> The students whose names I've called will come up onstage.

The above sentence shows that the teacher has already called the names of the students.  And then those students will have to go on stage.

Comment: The phrase needs to read **the students whose names I call** (**names** in the plural as they will all have different names)

Comment: Yeah right @ronaldsole but lea is wrong too i don't think substituting I will call with am going to call would make it grammatical

Comment: @user82287 Your suggestion was perfectly grammatical. Lea's is an alternative suggestion; it is also grammatical. The choice comes down to preference and context.